# MPV player time format HH:MM:SS or HH:MM:SS:mmm

Tags: milliseconds, timecodes, mpv

does anybody know, if it is possible to set default displayed time format including milliseconds in mpv.conf ?

Now I need click on time to switch to millisecnds, because option ,,timems'' from manual https://mpv.io/manual/master/ doesn't work.

Thanks for help
Peter

Answer (score 15):

[image: OSC (ON SCREEN CONTROLLER)]

from window:

click the LEFT timestamp

from command:

```
mpv .. --script-opts=osc-timems=yes ..
```

or add in `lua-settings/osc.conf`:

```
timems=yes
```

Answer (score 7):

`mpv --osd-fractions --osd-level=2`
or add to config

To toggle show - hide with keyboard, append to to input.conf:

```
 o cycle-values osd-level 2 1
#^-- or any other key
```

Answer (score 5):

yes, add the line `osd-fractions` to `mpv.conf`<s>`ig`</s>. this will show milliseconds in the OSD (which will appear in mpv's terminal display).

if you want to see milliseconds in the OSC (in the video window), also add the line `osd-level=2` to `mpv.conf`. this will add a status message with the OSD time display (which is now in milliseconds) to the top of the window.

Or you can click the time display on the video each time you load a video.

Comment: Thanks, using osd-fractions together with osd-level=2 now works for OSD.
But I suppose the same is not possible for time display? I need to click each time I load video.

Comment: For some reason I had to name the config file `mpv.conf` on my system. `mpv.config` does not get read.